# Caption on tables with wrapfigure

Tags: tables, floats, captions, wrapfigure

I'm simply trying to get a table on the right side of my text. I've tried many different packages like `float`, `floatflt`, and `wrapfig`, the latter got me the closest to what I wanted. My only issue at this point is that the caption says "Figure 1:" Whereas it should be a table. I can't use `\begin{table}` with `\begin{wrapfig}` since it screws things up.

Here is the full code for the table:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.24\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c || c | c | }
    \hline
      & a & b \\
    \hline \hline
    1 & 1 & 2 \\
    \hline
    2 & 3 & 2 \\
    \hline
    3 & 1 & 2 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table representation of the DFA in Figure \ref{fig:dfa_example}}
\label{DFA_table}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

[image]

As a side note, would it also be possible to get the table to be a little higher than the text (top margin)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is perhaps just informative in terms of float and caption interaction (even on a small scale such as in the original post).

The caption used inside a floating environment, including that of [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) checks `\@captype` in order to set the appropriate caption. You can modify `\@captype` to be `table` to obtain the appropriate caption style. For this, add

```
\makeatletter
\def\@captype{table}
\makeatother
```

before your `\caption` command. Using `wraptable` instead (as in Gonzalo's answer) is preferred, since it removes this kind of detail from the user interface. Why would you want to do this? Perhaps, instead of a `wraptable`, you have a small algorithm that you want to display but `wrapfig` does not provide a `wrapalgorithm` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{wrapfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.24\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ | c || c | c | }
    \hline
      & a & b \\
    \hline \hline
    1 & 1 & 2 \\
    \hline
    2 & 3 & 2 \\
    \hline
    3 & 1 & 2 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \makeatletter\def\@captype{table}\makeatother% "Change float to table"
  \caption{Table representation of the DFA in Figure 2.}
  \label{DFA_table}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

For vertical displacement, you can add

```
\vspace*{<len>}
```

where `<len>` is a negative length at the start of your `wrapfig`. This will move it up a bit. For example, using `\vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}` will move it up half a line.

Answer (score 8):

Use `wraptable` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{wraptable}{r}{0.24\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | c || c | c | }
    \hline
      & a & b \\
    \hline \hline
    1 & 1 & 2 \\
    \hline
    2 & 3 & 2 \\
    \hline
    3 & 1 & 2 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table representation of the DFA in Figure \ref{fig:dfa_example}}
\label{DFA_table}
\end{wraptable}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]